# string& and char* version of string::append(), string::replace() and string::compare()

Tags: c++, string

The two overloaded function in std::string got my attention:

```
string& append(const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n);
string& append(const char* s, size_t n);
```

I'm curious that why the char* version of string::append() doesn't provide an additional parameter `size_t pos`, as the one below:

```
string& append(const char* s, size_t pos, size_t n);
```

For the other two functions, the situation is also the same:

```
int compare(size_t pos1, size_t n1, const string& str, size_t pos2, size_t n2) const;
int compare(size_t pos1, size_t n1, const char* s, size_t n2) const;

string& replace(size_t pos1, size_t n1, const string& str, size_t pos2, size_t n2);
string& replace(size_t pos1, size_t n1, const char* s, size_t n2);
```

The char* version of these functions lack the parameter `size_t pos2`, which is not as flexible as their string& counterpart. My question is the following:

1. Why does std::string design its interface like this?
2. Why doesn't the char* version function has `size_t pos` as well?
3. What's the consideration(s) behind this?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you can just add `pos` to `s`:

```
str.append(ptr + pos, len);
```

That isn't to say it wouldn't be a nice shorthand to have, but they (generally) only want to minimally add the necessary functions, not the trivial wrapper kind.

Comment: Besides, `str.append(ptr, pos, len);` is only one char shorter than `str.append(ptr + pos, len);` (and that depends on your whitespaces habits).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could do simply `str.append(s+pos, n);`